# Heroku/Dash app Python, reading file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, plotly-dash

I have a dash web app deployed on Heroku, and it needs to read a .csv file located on Google Cloud Storage. To do this, I give to the app the credentials to access to my Google Cloud account, and then, I can load the file with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv")
```

This .csv file is updated regularly but the updates are not taken into account by the application.

The application load the file when deployed but then, it never re-load the file and so, it never takes updates into account until I deploy it again.

Is there a way to force the app read the file each time I refresh the web browser so that each update is taken into account ?

Thank you in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think a [decorator](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator) would be usefull here. Please do take into account that depending on the size of the file you might get some extra latency as it needs to reload the `df` each time.
You'll need to decorate each view that needs the `df` to be reloaded.

Another one would be to set up a specific endpoint that forces a reload of the `df` and use Heroku's [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to call that endpoint. This will remove the extra latency on the other requests, but it will make it show *stale data* sometimes.

See this short example below...

```py
import Flask
from functools import wraps
import pandas as pd 


app = Flask(__name__)
df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv")


def reload_df(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        global df
        df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.route("/")
@reload_df
def index():
    return "hello world"


@app.route("/not_reloading_df")
def index():
    return "still using previous DF"


@app.route("/forcereload")
@reload_df
def force_reload():
    return "Reloaded DF"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am not very familiar with dash yet. I don't know about Flask and the links between flask and dash ...

I found that, I need to restart dyno so that the files are reloaded. To restart dyno, I just need to use the following command:

`heroku dyno:restart`

Then files are reloaded. So in my case, I need to use this command each time my csv file is updated

Comment: So Flask is a framework for webapps. Heroku Dash is meant for webapps. I mean, you state you need to reload the webpage, so you're providing a webapp somehow. Which framekwork (if any) are you using for this. Regardless, putting the decorator in front of whatever endpoints your app provides will do what you want, but I would still advise to use the specific `forcereload` endpoint to reduce latency...

Comment: I didn't manage to make your explanation work sadly, but it's because I'm not very experienced. Maybe I will understand later.

I found another way to reload the csv at each page refresh: I have a callback in the app, as described here:

[link](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)

and if I include:

`global df
df = pd.read_csv("gs://bucket_name/file_name.csv")`
inside this call back, the files are reloaded at each refresh